# DELETE your copy of jquery UI from the js folder

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i use jquery-ui.min.js in my plugin js folder i include that in a function where i want to use jquery

i include it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo OEPL_USERTOCRM_PLUGIN_URL.'js/jquery-ui.min.js' ?>"></script>
```

but now i want to upload this plugin for other user and wordpress says that 
"* DO NOT include your own copy of javascript files that are already included in WordPress Core
* DO NOT make remote calls to javascript files that are already included in WordPress Core

Please DELETE your copy of jquery UI from the js folder"

i used this js for toggle bar like on and off switch type...
i do not know what to do now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to use jQuery UI Library then you should just include in your plugin because its already in wordpress core. And remove from anywhere , where you used external source. 
You can include like this.

wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core");

Comment: i did this but not working....in my plugin config file----> function my_switchbutton_function(){
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core");
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_switchbutton_function');

Comment: you are on the right way ... i will suggest to you that . please debug code line by line. you find issue and solve your self.

Comment: May be you need to use that one too, : -wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-effects-fade' );

Comment: i think the problem is in my code...because this jquery isn't including in my wordpressnow will do some debugging as my function is not working i guess